# error: could not lock config file error on Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, gerrit

I'm running a docker container and mounting a volume which needs to be accessed from inside the container and it fails with the below error.

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 29418:29418 -e CANONICAL_WEB_URL=http://ec2-18-21-19-32.us-east-2ompute.amazonaws.com:8080 \
>  -v '/home/gerrit/gerrit_instance/gerrit_vol/etc:/var/gerrit/etc' \
>  --env CANONICAL_WEB_URL=http://ec2-18-219-190-32.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080 gerritimage
error: could not lock config file /var/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config: Permission denied
```

Docker installed on Ubuntu

If i run this image without the volume it works perfectly. The instant i want to add my custom file this error is reported.

In the container these files are populated automatically with the init script

Link followed to build and execute the file

docker pull gerritcodereview/gerrit
https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/docker-gerrit

The steps are identical and i'm just uploading the etc directory which needs to be mounted to the gerrit container.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Anish